# Code is throwing catch exception when entering a file name

Tags: error-handling

I have written a code to check for delimiters from an inputted file name.  No matter what filename I put in I always get my exception of Fine Not Found. Please try again.  What am I missing here?  I have tried entering different files I have already in eclipse.  I also tried entering numbersonnumbers.txt.  Everything gives me the same error and I can't figure it out.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Stack;

class DelimiterChecker {
    private BufferedReader reader;
    private int lineNumber = 1;
    private int charNumber = 0;

    public DelimiterChecker(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    }

    public Character getNextCharacter() throws IOException {
        int charCode;
        char character;

        while ((charCode = reader.read()) != -1) {
            charNumber++;
            character = (char) charCode;

            // Check for comments, literals, and skip
            if (character == '/') {
                if (reader.markSupported()) {
                    reader.mark(1);
                    char nextChar = (char) reader.read();
                    if (nextChar == '/') {
                        // Single-line comment, skip until the end of the line
                        while (character != '\n' && charCode != -1) {
                            charCode = reader.read();
                            character = (char) charCode;
                            charNumber++;
                        }
                        lineNumber++;
                        charNumber = 0;
                    } else if (nextChar == '*') {
                        // Multi-line comment, skip until "*/"
                        boolean commentEnd = false;
                        while (!commentEnd && charCode != -1) {
                            charCode = reader.read();
                            character = (char) charCode;
                            charNumber++;
                            if (character == '*') {
                                reader.mark(1);
                                char next = (char) reader.read();
                                if (next == '/') {
                                    commentEnd = true;
                                }
                            } else if (character == '\n') {
                                lineNumber++;
                                charNumber = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        reader.reset();
                        return character;
                    }
                } else {
                    return character;
                }
            } else if (character == '"') {
                // String literal, skip until the closing double quote
                while ((character != '"' || (character == '"' && charCode > 0 && (char) reader.read() == '\\')) && charCode != -1) {
                    charCode = reader.read();
                    character = (char) charCode;
                    charNumber++;
                }
            } else if (character == '\'') {
                // Character literal, skip until the closing single quote
                while ((character != '\'' || (character == '\'' && charCode > 0 && (char) reader.read() == '\\')) && charCode != -1) {
                    charCode = reader.read();
                    character = (char) charCode;
                    charNumber++;
                }
            } else if (character == '\n') {
                lineNumber++;
                charNumber = 0;
            } else {
                return character;
            }
        }
        return null; // End of file
    }

    public String getCurrentPosition() {
        return "Line " + lineNumber + ", Char " + charNumber;
    }
}

public class DelimiterMatching {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String fileName;
        DelimiterChecker delimiterChecker;

        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");
                fileName = keyboard.readLine();
                delimiterChecker = new DelimiterChecker(fileName);
                break;
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File not found. Please try again.");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error reading input. Please try again.");
            }
        }

        Stack<Character> delimiterStack = new Stack<>();
        Character currentChar;
        int position = 1;

        try {
            while ((currentChar = delimiterChecker.getNextCharacter()) != null) {
                if ("([{".contains(currentChar.toString())) {
                    delimiterStack.push(currentChar);
                } else if (")]}".contains(currentChar.toString())) {
                    if (delimiterStack.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println("Mismatched right delimiter '" + currentChar + "' at " + delimiterChecker.getCurrentPosition());
                        return;
                    }
                    char leftDelimiter = delimiterStack.pop();
                    if ((currentChar == ')' && leftDelimiter != '(') || (currentChar == ']' && leftDelimiter != '[') || (currentChar == '}' && leftDelimiter != '{')) {
                        System.out.println("Mismatched delimiters: '" + leftDelimiter + "' and '" + currentChar + "' at " + delimiterChecker.getCurrentPosition());
                        return;
                    }
                }
                position++;
            }

            if (!delimiterStack.isEmpty()) {
                char leftDelimiter = delimiterStack.pop();
                System.out.println("Mismatched left delimiter '" + leftDelimiter + "' at the end of the file.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Delimiters are properly matched.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error reading input.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's way too much irrelevant code right now.

Comment: While I know nothing about Java, pretty sure `FileReader` expects file name with path, like `C://your/file.txt` not just file name